# User.find does not finds the record. What is the correction needed?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, passport.js

I'm using Mongoose for MongoDB integration in Node.js along with PassportJS.

Defining schema for Twitter:

```
 var twitterUserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
      account: { provider: String, 
                 id: String}, 
      username: String,
      name: String,
      displayName: String,
      email: String,
  });

var twitterUser= mongoose.model('twitterUser', twitterUserSchema);
var twitterUserInstance = new twitterUser;
```

Using Authentication Strategy provided by `passport-twitter`:

```
passport.use(new TwitterStrategy({
 consumerKey: TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY,
 consumerSecret: TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET,
 callbackURL: "/auth/twitter/callback"
},

function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done)
     {process.nextTick(function () {
        twitterUser.find({account: {id: profile.id}}, function(err, Tuser) {
         console.log(TIU.length);
```

In the above code,

```
twitterUser.find({account: {id: profile.id}, function(err, Tuser) {
         console.log(Tuser.length);
```

always prints `Tuser.length` as `0`, even if the exact `id` exists in the database.

Comment: You are missing a `}` at the end of `{account: {id: profile.id}`

Comment: No thats not it. Sorry for the typo here.

Comment: are you sure you are passing in the right "type" of id. By that I mean does it expect an ObjectID but you are passing it a string